# WPF How can i make a button in "L" form

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, button, styles

I would like my button to have the shape of the letter "L" as in this picture [Simple Paint Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrJ0s.png). The only examples I can find are if you want the button to be round or like a lemon. I know that I need to use template but how exactly I don't understand.

The Code is in the App.xaml for global using.

```
<!--#region LButton-->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="LButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Grid Width="100" Height="100">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderBrush="Black" Background="LightGreen">
               <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Button.Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
<!--#endregion-->
```

I know i can add CornerRadius="30,30,30,30" that the Button has Rounded Corners.

Thx for your help. Best Regards Shazzar

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes I have already searched unfortunately without success if the question already exists I am sorry that I asked them again

Comment: @Shazzar - The issue is that you haven't shown us any evidence of you having tried this yourself (if you have, please post your code). You need to at least show some effort before you expect others to put in any for you.

Comment: Yeah I understand what you mean but what does show you the code where no real results are. I post him but it is very simple and I thought you guys don't need something like this.

Comment: I would use a Button, and have its' controlTemplate set to DrawingImage. Then create a vector of what you want the shape to be like, push it through VS Blend. This will give you a path, that you can set as Drawing Image -> Drawing Group -> Geometry Drawing. I'll try to post a complete example this evening, when I get access to PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by overwriting the Control Template.  Here is a very rough example to get you started.

**EDIT** Updated Path to be L shape

```
    <Button >
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <Polygon Points="300,200 200,200 200,300 250,300 250,250 300,250" Fill="Purple" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Great that works perfectly for me. Now i can move the Points like i want. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.LButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
              <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Name="upButton" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="1" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=upButton}"></Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I created two buttons one is the up part and other for the down part, then I used binding between the two buttons in order to get the same style.

I think that you can not create an *LButton* using only one button.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I need a button in the form as in the picture that you can use two buttons the idea I had synonymous.